# Kotlin/Room/Android Error: Getting error while Querying for nested object which can have null fields

Tags: android, json, database, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to request data from an API which responds with an array of nested JSON object in which some entries of the object can be null.

Each of the object has a structure similar to the following :

```
data class A(
  @ColumnInfo("item1InA")
  val item1InA:Double?=null,
  @ColumnInfo("item2InA")
  val item2InA:Double?=null,
)

data class B(
  @ColumnInfo("item1InB")
  val item1InB:Double?=null,
  @ColumnInfo("item2InB")
  val item2InB:Double?=null,
)

@Entity(tableName="temp_table")
data class Combination(
  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  @ColumnInfo("key")
  val key:String='-',
  @ColumnInfo("originalItem1")
  val originalItem1:String='-',
  @ColumnInfo("originalItem2")
  val originalItem2:String='-',
  @Embedded
  val a:A=A(),
  @Embedded 
  val b:B=B(),
)
```

I am querying the database in the application to get the list of the all Combination objects using the following interface :

```
@Dao
interface CombinationDao{
  @Query("SELECT * FROM temp_table")
  suspend fun getAll():List<Combination>
}
```

The issue is that i am getting the error: **java.lang.NullPointerExceptio**n: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method **kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter**

When I checked on the directed links to the CombinationDao_Impl.java file, I got the following error: **both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other**

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help me get on the right track?

**Sample JSON**

```
{
  "A":{
    "item1InA":23.0,
    "item2InA":null,
   },
  "B":{
    "item1InB":67327.309,
    "item2InB":null,
   },
  "key":"thisIsUnique",
  "originalItem1":"hello",
  "originalItem2":"world",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation at [Embedded | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Embedded),

> When an embedded field is read, if all fields of the embedded field (and its sub fields) are null in the Cursor, it is set to null. Otherwise, it is constructed

The issue with my code was that for some JSON objects each of the fields of the embedded objects were null causing room to simply ignore to construct the object making the variables **a** and **b** to point at null.

Changing the code of the entity class to,

```
data class Combination(
  @PrimaryKey
  @NonNull
  @ColumnInfo("key")
  val key:String='-',
  @ColumnInfo("originalItem1")
  val originalItem1:String='-',
  @ColumnInfo("originalItem2")
  val originalItem2:String='-',
  @Embedded
  val a:A?=A(),
  @Embedded 
  val b:B?=B(),
)
```

solved the issue for me.